# Wuala error: "Failed to find Java VM" even when Java is installed

Tags: windows, 64-bit, wuala

I have just installed [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com), some kind of Dropbox equivalent, and, when I start it, a window appear telling "**Failed to find Java VM**".

I already have a Java VM installed, but I have checked again, and the Java VM is installed and be launched from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wuala requires the following line to be present in the wuala.ini file (on Windows 7 is located here `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Wuala`):

`vm.location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0\bin\client\jvm.dll`

Note the above path is applicable to Windows 7 64-bit, for JRE 6 32-bit.
Also note that Wuala does not start when using the server dll of the JRE 7 64-bit.

Comment: Only god knows why the JRE7 x64 server dll doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Wuala also show this message but for different reason. Wuala installer will install 32-bit Java VM if it is not present on the system. Sometime later, the 32-bit Java VM gets uninstalled for some reason, perhaps when some update removes older insecure VM and replaces it with new one, which happens to be 64-bit. Wuala then stops working.

The solution is to install both 32-bit and 64-bit Java VM side by side by downloading offline 32-bit installer from java.com. This is a supported configuration, although it's not the default. Reinstalling Wuala does the job too as it triggers installation of the right Java VM.